# Every new SAPUI5 Project is showing a blank page

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have every time when I am setting up a new sapui5 project, that nothing is shown, only a blank page.

I looked already at the console, some things are missing. I already changed the index.html, language and tried different things from the internet.
Once I had the problem, it solves suddenly itself. I also reset the cache, what works once for me. I am using the local sap web IDE.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <title>test_chart</title>

        <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
            src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize"
            data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
            data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"test_charttest_chart": ""}'>
        </script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

        <script>
            sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function() {
                new sap.m.Shell({
                    app: new sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer({
                        height : "100%",
                        name : "test_charttest_chart"
                    })
                }).placeAt("content");
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body class="sapUiBody" id="content">
    </body>

</html>
```

[image: chrome network tab]

[image: console]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to add an answer (since the problem is solved).. The issue was that the app was trying to load resources that are available only in SAPUI5 but not in *Open*UI5 (e.g. `sap.ushell`).

> ```html
> <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" ...>
> ```
>
> Failed to load `sap/ushell/library.js` from ...

If you have an appropriate license for using SAPUI5 **from CDN**, simply replace `src="https://openui5.hana...."` with a destination to SAPUI5 resources (e.g. `src="https://sapui5.hana...."`).

In order to keep using OpenUI5, look for SAPUI5 dependencies in `index.html` and `manifest.json`, and remove them.